# Restoring a branch that was overwritten with rename (git branch -M)

Tags: git

I initially had a branch, but I accidentally overwritten it with another branch with git branch -M command.

Is there a way to restore a overwritten branch (hash)?

Reflog doesn't show any previous commit hash, and I cannot find a commit hash for the original branch anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I made a test.

```
$ git branch
* master
$ git reflog master
63fa031 master@{0}: clone: from git://192.168.70.128/
$ git branch -M master nice
$ git branch
* nice
$ git reflog master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
$ git reflog nice
63fa031 nice@{0}: Branch: renamed refs/heads/master to refs/heads/nice
63fa031 nice@{1}: clone: from git://192.168.70.128/
```

So `git reflog <newbranch>` can show the rename history.

Comment: It only shows the history of overwritting branch. I want the history of "overwritten" branch.

Comment: @SHH in my case the "overwritten" branch was pointing to 63fa031, or `nice@{0}`, when its name was changed.  `git log 63fa031` could show its commit history. `git checkout -b master 63fa031` can restore it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems renaming a branch also renames (and in your case, overwrites) its reflog, so you cannot access the reflog of the overwritten branch anymore.

But the commit hash can still be mentioned in `git reflog`, because it logs branch checkouts. If that commit is not mentioned in reflog (or you are not sure whether it is), try `git fsck --no-reflogs`, it will list (among other things) all the dangling commits, one of which should be the head of your overwritten branch.